# AJAX Jquery request error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" error, when i take out the below snippet the error goes away. Maybe its because ive been up all night but i cant for the life of me find the issue. Can anyone please shed some light?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/getWorkerPendingJobs.php",
    type: "get",
    data: {uid: userId},
    success: function(dataa) {
        var daa = JSON.parse(dataa);
        var amtt = parseInt(daa.length);
        var htmll = "";
        if (amtt > 0) {
            $.each(daa, function(indexx) {
                var status;
                var acc = daa[indexx].accepted.toString();
                if (acc == 1) {
                    status = "Pending";
                }
                if (acc == 2) {
                    status = "Accepted";
                }

                htmll += '<li><a href="" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop" longDesc="' + daa[indexx].description + '" id="' + daa[indexx].id + '" shortDesc="' + daa[indexx].shortdesc + '" budget="' + daa[indexx].budget + '" accepted="' + daa[indexx].accepted + '"><img src="./noimage.png" /><h3>' + daa[indexx].dateadded + ' | ' + daa[indexx].shortdesc + '</h3><h2>Status : ' + status + '</h2><p>' + daa[indexx].description + '</p></a></li>';
                $('.worker-applied-jobs').html(htmll).promise().done(function() {
                    $(this).listview("refresh");
                });
            });
        } else {
            $('.worker-applied-jobs').html('<p style="margin-left:10px;">You have not applied for any jobs.</p>');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Check the line which throws the error and post it here. It could be `JSON.parse()`

Comment: the error seems to be from the file that the ajax is quering,you haven't closed a function or someting similar

Comment: Remove the code within success then try.

Comment: check your console for `console.log(daa);` and also check for syntax for your  `.listview` see it it accepts the html that you have provided

Comment: Ah it was something in the php file you are right, i thought it was a client side issue. Thanks!

Comment: i believe problem with passing variable into your php file, instead of data: {uid: userId}, pass like this data: {'uid': userId},